# how to add a line break or <br/> after every list item using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 100 list items and to make it look nicer i want to add a line break tag after the end of every list item. So how can I do it using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Could you add your attempt, please?

Comment: From list, do you mean ul and li?

Comment: i mean after every li

Comment: you should use CSS

Comment: For valid HTML you *can't* add break tags *after* `li` tags. You can add them *inside* the `li` tag, but *not* after. Ideally this is what padding and margins in CSS are for. You should try and avoid using break tags to create space.

Comment: `<li>` will break by default, unless you or someone else has changed the CSS for `li` to something like `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, I used [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) (jquery) to insert `<br/>` after each `li`

```js
$(function(){

  $("<br/>").insertAfter("li")
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>ITEM 1</li>  
  <li>ITEM 2</li>  
  <li>ITEM 3</li>  
  <li>ITEM 4</li>  
</ul>
```

But, you don't need JavaScript for doing this, you could do this easily by **CSS**

```css
ul > li{
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use CSS, this demo has over 100 list items and I spaced each one with one style.

#### SNIPPET

```css
li { 
  margin-bottom:15px;
  }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  </ol>
```